# Why provide the `HasCallStack` mechanism since we already have `ghc -prof -fprof-auto-top` in GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc, callstack

AFAIK, there are two ways to get a call stack for debugging in Haskell:

1. add `HasCallStack` constraint in the code
2. compile code with `ghc -prof -fprof-auto-top`

My test code:

```
import GHC.Stack

-- | a wrapper function to make "last" from base traceable
last' :: HasCallStack => [a] -> a
last' xs = case xs of [] -> error "abuse last"; _ -> last xs

-- | a untraceable partial function
foo :: [Int] -> Int
foo xs = last' xs + 1

-- | a untraceable partial function
-- , which looks like traceable, but it's call stack is cut off by "foo"
bar :: HasCallStack => [Int] -> Int
bar xs = foo xs

-- | an empty list
-- , which is also an improper input of "last'"
xs :: [Int]
xs = []

-- | the program is expected to print a call stack telling how "bar" is called
-- , but we can only know that "foo" called "last'" improperly from the printed call stack
main :: IO ()
main = print $ bar xs
```

Following is the call stack I get from both of the above two ways with [this](https://gist.github.com/luochen1990/94179a2492ff7d1ca45153645f1bb449) test code:

```
$ ghc -prof -fprof-auto call-stack-cut-off.hs
$ ./call-stack-cut-off
call-stack-cut-off: abuse last
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at call-stack-cut-off.hs:5:29 in main:Main
  last', called at call-stack-cut-off.hs:9:10 in main:Main
CallStack (from -prof):
  Main.last' (call-stack-cut-off.hs:5:1-60)
  Main.foo (call-stack-cut-off.hs:9:1-21)
  Main.bar (call-stack-cut-off.hs:14:1-15)
  Main.main (call-stack-cut-off.hs:24:1-21)
  Main.CAF (<entire-module>)
```

IMO, the call stack from `-prof` is already good enough and is easier to use. So I'm wondering why the `HasCallStack` mechanism is added yet. Is there some difference between these two way which will significantly affect the debugging experience?

Answer (score 6):

`HasCallStack` has a few basic advantages:

1. It’s lighter-weight, not needing `-prof`, so it doesn’t require recompilation (because profiled code has a different ABI than non-profiled code)
2. It gives you more control over what’s included in the call stack, based on where you place `HasCallStack` constraints and where you use `withFrozenCallStack` to prevent irrelevant/internal details from showing up in traces
3. It allows you to access the call stack from within the program itself using `getCallStack`, so you can incorporate it into messages for logging, exceptions, and so on

Comment: Point 1 is a bit misleading: if you add `HasCallStack` you surely have to recompile to make it have an effect. What I think you mean is that you do not need to recompile everything else (other modules & libraries) like when turning profiling on.